# Does Water mean my city has a finite lifespan?

Tags: simcity-2013

In the new Sim City recently made available, the amount of water available to a city is finite. The same is true of it's neighbours; limiting what can be bought in -- and if playing with other people they'd seem unlikely to just give you all of their precious water.

The other "constant" services that are required (Power, Garbage Collection and Sewage removal) can be basically unlimited. I can use Wind/Solar for Power, incinerate garbage, treat/dump sewage...

But... how can I deal with the water in my city running out in a sustainable way?

Answer (score 0):

If you build a water pump with a treatment plant nearby your waste disposal, my understanding is that you will get water from the pump forever.